# Requests are NOT capture in Jmeter to run Performance Testing for Desktop application

Tags: performance-testing, desktop-application

There is a desktop application which uses HTTP/HTTPS which needs to be done for performance testing.

I have configured `Network Proxy settings -> localhost/8888` and Also configured 'same proxy in Jmeter' 8888

I am currently recording the desktop application to do few functions.. But nothing is getting captured in the Jmeter.

Some directions would be appreciative

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure to add JMeter's self-signed certificate to [Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/manage-trusted-root-certificates-windows)

   [image]
2. You might also need to install [Microsoft Loopback Adapter](https://nil.uniza.sk/how-install-microsoft-loopback-adapter-windows-10/)

   [image]
3. Ensure that JMeter is capable of reaching out to the backend, i.e. if you're using proxy for Internet access - [make JMeter aware of this proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

More information: [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter/)

Comment: Point 1 is sure done. Point 3 is also done mostly.. Point 2 is mandatory for this?